# Need to compare Two strings on a dataframe using applymap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

On a Dataframe I have around 20 records having few columns and one of the two columns are  "Orig.Req" and "Mod.Req"

I have written a function `color_change`, on which I have to compare the two strings record by record on these two columns and return the color to print on the syle.

```
import pandas as pd

def color_change(value):
    """
    Returns color with red if the requirement is changed.
    """
    print(value) 
    #  Value here prints out all the fields under orig_req and then the mod_req. 
    #  I want to compare the variables of each columns row by row. 
    #  Is this possible?

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df2.to_string(index = False)
df2.style.applymap(color_change, subset=['orig_Req','mod_Req'])
```

Comment: Could you include some dummy data? And could you specify what should be printed out and under what condition?

Comment: Is it ok for you to use `apply` instead of `applymap` since `applymap` can only work [element-wise](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Building-styles) while `apply` can work for rows and columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap.html) is elementwise, you can only access current element. If you want to compare by row-wise, you can try [`Styler.apply(func, axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html).

```py
def color_change(row):
    """
    Returns color with red if the requirement is changed.
    """
    print(row['orig_Req'])
    print(row['mod_Req']) 

df2.style.apply(color_change, subset=['orig_Req','mod_Req'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solves my purpose. But the portion of applying the color does not work   But i get this error while applying the style 
ValueError: Function <function color_change at 0x7fd23b272e60> returned the wrong shape.
Result has shape: (6,)
Expected shape:   (6, 2)..

Comment: The following code works                                                                                                     def color_change(row):
    """
    Returns color with red if the requirement is changed.
    """
    #print(row['orig_Req'])
    #print(row['mod_Req'])

    return ['background-color: yellow' if row['orig_Req'] != row['mod_Req'] else ''
                for v in row]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
display(df2)
#df2.to_string(index = False)
df2.style.apply(color_change, subset=['orig_Req','mod_Req'], axis=1)